# Prove that there are infinitely many relatively prime solutions of $x^2+y^2=z^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Show that for all integers k, there is a solution with

$x=3k^2-1$ and

$z=k^2+1$

You will need to calculate $y$ to show that there is such a solution, and show that the solution $(x,y,z)$ is relatively prime.

So I calculated that $y=k^3-3k$, but I have to show that $x,y,z$ are all relatively prime. Halp.

Comment: I see what you mean, the problem states all integers k, but if k is odd, then $x,y,z$ are even which isn't relatively prime.

Comment: It is $x^2+y^2=z^3$

Comment: Sorry, fuzzy display. Need a new computer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334839/pythagorean-triplets-x2y2-z3/724370#724370

Comment: Look at the formula there. I think useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be even. We show that no prime $p$ can divide both $x$ and $z$. Suppose to the contrary that $p$ divides $3k^2-1$ and $p$ divides $k^2+1$. Then $p$ divides $3(k^2+1)-(3k^2-1)$, so $p$ divides $4$. This forces $p=2$, which is impossible if $k$ is even.

The three numbers are not pairwise relatively prime if $k$ is odd, for if $k$ is odd then all three numbers are even.

**Remark:** Note that the three numbers are pairwise relatively prime if and only if $x$ and $z$ are relatively prime. For example, let us show that if $x$ and $z$ are relatively prime, so are $x$ and $y$. Suppose to the contrary that $x$ and $y$ are not relatively prime. Then some prime $p$ divides $x$ and $y$. It follows that $p$ divides $x^2+y^2$, and therefore $p$ divides $z^3$, and therefore $p$ divides $z$, contradicting the fact that $x$ and $z$ are relatively prime.

Comment: You are using the argument that if $p \mid x$ and $p \mid y$ then $p \mid (ax-by)$?

Comment: Yes. For that part I do not need $p$ to be prime, but in proving results, using primes is often useful. Example: the argument in the remark.

Comment: I see. Thanks, Mr. Nicolas

Comment: You are welcome.