# What is the set of numbers which satisfy equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $d^3$ also?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
 Then I got a problem when I thought what about having 
Ann number or set of numbers which will satisfy
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
And also $a^2 + b^2 = d^3$ 
Both the equation simultaneously for example 
$3^2 + 4^2 = 25$
But $25$ is not a cubic number 
I want to know that sum of two square numbers can be equal to a square and a cubic number for $n^6$?
I am not asking about Pythagorean triplets I am asking which satisfies $d^3$?

Comment: You should let $a, b, c, d > 0$ to exclude the trivial cases.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $$a,b,c,d$$?

Comment: I want the numbers a , b , c , d

Comment: Your question is already answered in [Variation of Pythagorean triplets: $x^2+y^2 = z^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334839/variation-of-pythagorean-triplets-x2y2-z3).

Comment: So $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers? But $1^2 + 1^2 = (\sqrt{2})^2$ and $1^2+1^2 = (\sqrt[3]{2})^3$.

Comment: Since $c^2=d^3$, $c$ has to be a cube, and $d$ has to be a square. Also, $d^3$ has to be of the form $4n$ or $4n+1$... My 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example - you can find others by searching for triangles for which the hypotenuse happens to be a cube.
$$
117^2 + 44^2 = 125^2 = 25^3.
$$

You can always manufacture one with a cheap trick:
Whenever 
$$
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
$$
you know
$$
(ac^2)^2 + (bc^2)^2 = c^6
$$
which is both a square and a cube. For the $3-4-5$ triangle that yields
$$
75^2 + 100^2 = 125^2 = 25^3 .
$$